# putting '0' before ID number that the user input

Tags: c

I'm a new c programmer.
I was asked to get an ID number as an input and if the ID length < 9 I need to put '0' before the number.
example:
input: 12345
output: 000012345

I can use the libraries: stdio, stdlib, string, math and time.

Comment: For trailing 0's you better use string type.

Comment: yes of course, but I can only think about a lot of if's... if ID.length < 1.. and on and on

Comment: oh ok, that makes matters a lot easier actually

Comment: I can use string library, sorry I edited.

Comment: The `printf` family of functions is so flexible that introductory treatment always only skim over the surface. But if you are actually going to use c you should read the full description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `printf` for this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   printf("%09d\n", 12345);
   return(0);
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

Comment: thank you! a lot easier than a couple of if's

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution in here.

But if you want a hard solution, where you juggle around with strings and such, you can do the following:

- convert your id into a string (if it isn't already one, but argv should a string by default)
- calculate the number of zeros you need, by doing 9-idString Length
- create a "buffer" string variable
- for loop from 0 to 9-idString and use strcat to add "0"s to your buffer string.
- add your id to your buffer string using strcat

Example code would be something like this:

```
int id = 12345;

char idstring[10];
char buffer[10];

sprintf(idstring, "%d", id);

int missingZerosCount = 9 - strlen(idstring);

strcpy(buffer, "");

while (missingZerosCount > 0) {
    strcat(buffer, "0");
    missingZerosCount--;
}
strcat(buffer, idstring);
```

argv variant:

```
char idstring[10];
char buffer[10];

sprintf(idstring, "%s", argv[1]);

int missingZerosCount = 9 - strlen(idstring);

strcpy(buffer, "");

while (missingZerosCount > 0) {
    strcat(buffer, "0");
    missingZerosCount--;
}
strcat(buffer, idstring);
```